# How can I make the Ubuntu 17.04 login screen look like Mac OSX?

Tags: themes, login-screen

I need to make Ubuntu look like Mac OSX, specifically the login screen.

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: https://github.com/Wattos/LightDM-Webkit-MacOSX-Theme

Comment: $ /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
bash: /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf: No such file or directory

can you help me?

Comment: It's a flie, not a command, and you're supposed to edit. Open it with `sudo -H gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` or `sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the instructions in the [link](https://github.com/Wattos/LightDM-Webkit-MacOSX-Theme) I provided in the comments, here is how I installed and configured it on my system:

1. Install `git` (if not installed).  `sudo apt install git`
2. Installed `webkit-greeter` (if not installed).  `sudo apt install lightdm-webkit-greeter`
3. `cd ~/Downloads`
4. `git clone https://github.com/Wattos/LightDM-Webkit-MacOSX-Theme`
5. `cd LightDM-Webkit-MacOSX-Theme/`
6. `sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/lightdm-webkit/themes/mac`
7. If `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` does not exist, `sudo bash -c 'echo "[SeatDefaults]" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'`
8. `sudo bash -c 'echo "greeter-session=lightdm-webkit-greeter" >> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'`
9. `sudo cp -rv * /usr/share/lightdm-webkit/themes/mac`
10. `sudo sed -i 's/webkit-theme=default/webkit-theme=mac/' /etc/lightdm/lightdm-webkit-greeter.conf`
11. `sudo reboot`

Now when my greeter comes up it looks just like the image in the question.

Hope this helps!